# In or on invitation

Tags: prepositions

I am trying to write this sentence in a letter.

> Please use the contact information "in the invitation" or "on the invitation".

Which phrase should I use?

Comment: You could dodge that with "Please use the contact information provided with the invitation."

Comment: information [printed] on the invitation//information [contained] in the invitation. Your choice.

Comment: If there is only one location for the contact information, and it is not "buried" where it cannot easily be found, no need to specify where it is.

Answer (score 0):

**In** is more appropriate if you are referring to information literally contained within the content of the invitation.  **On** is used more to refer to the address of the invitation.  For example,

> [Bidders shall complete, execute and submit their bids in strict compliance with the instructions contained in the invitation for bids](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kentucky_Administrative_Regulations_Serv/YahMAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22in%20the%20invitation%22&dq=%22in%20the%20invitation%22&printsec=frontcover)

> [her name should appear on the invitation](https://books.google.com/books?id=_nz0jK0MJlkC&pg=PA24&dq=%22on%20the%20invitation%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdhuCM3qHvAhWmneAKHSkJBsM4ChDoATAFegQIBxAC)